# How do I save response data from URLSession.shared.dataTask to an mp3?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an api that takes an http POST parameter as json and responds with an mp3 file **in the same session**. I can't figure out how to take the data response and save it as an mp3 for playing in the app later. Targeting iOS 13.

```
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("error: \(error)")
        } else {
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("statusCode: \(response.statusCode)")
            }
            if let data = data {

                //---------- What goes here? ---------

            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Why not make this easier and use a download task instead of a data task?

Comment: Where is the mp3?  Is it `data`? Then just save it.

Comment: @rmaddy I think a download task requires a file that can be found at a url. This is more ephemeral in the sense that the file doesn't exist until the POST request is made. Once the POST request is made, the file is in the response.

Comment: @matt It is data. How should I save it so that it can be played back later?

Comment: If `data`, just use `data.write(to: fileURL)` to save it to file, it will become mp3 if the fileURL have `.mp3` extension